# JMETER -- want to call response (response data -- body) to body data of other HTTP request)

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

Hi I am new to JMETER and not sure what could be the possible solution for my query.

I have a scenario from my application which

1. Create new invoice (unique invoice number all the time, say 141, 142, 143...)
2. Enter/ Select details
3. Save invoice (BODY data have invoice number as 141)

I have recorded script for this using Blazemeter.

Now when execute the script, the API call for new invoice always generates a new and unique invoice (as I can see from listener - View result tree) but when it tries to save, it fails with error **Duplicate invoice number**, which is as expected.

If I replace the new body data's invoice number with new unique number (142), it saves the new invoice successfully in application but same script will fail again as body data have 142 and that invoice number was being created already.

Any solution / comments to this problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough so I can provide only generic piece of advice: parameterize these invoice numbers using suitable [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

1. If you want to increment the number by 1 - [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)
2. [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) generates an incremented number each time it's being called
3. [__strReplace()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) allows replacing one substring with another